# Create implicit rows in CSS grid

Tags: css, css-grid

I have a simple CSS grid.

I would like to have the `#right` and the `main` element under each other on a mobile view (800px width).

I thought that adding this:

```
main,
#right {
    grid-column: 2 / span 2;
}
```

would put the `main` and `#right` element under each other, but no such luck. It seems they both have a 100% height causing them to overlap.

So what I would like to see is:

```
main {
    margin-top: 90%;
    height: 50%;
}
#right {
    height: 50%;
}
```

But then of course caused by the CSS grid.

https://plnkr.co/edit/J0gZRP9LUak4n6eebnhh?p=preview

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}

#grid-wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template: "header header header" 66px "subheader subheader subheader" 55px "left main right" auto / 18.75% auto 25%;
}

header {
  grid-area: header;
  display: grid;
  grid-template: "logo searchbar hamburgermenu" auto / 18.75% auto 25%;
}

header #logo {
  grid-area: logo;
  background: red;
}

header #searchbar {
  grid-area: searchbar;
  background: yellow;
}

header #hamburgermenu {
  grid-area: hamburgermenu;
  background: teal;
}

.subheader {
  grid-area: subheader;
  display: grid;
  grid-template: ". telephone-content ." auto / 18.75% auto 25%;
  background: wheat;
}

.subheader .telephone-content {
  grid-area: telephone-content;
  background: lightcoral;
}

#left {
  grid-area: left;
  background: darkgray;
}

main {
  grid-area: main;
  background: lightskyblue;
}

#right {
  grid-area: right;
  background: lightsalmon;
}


/* TABLET VIEW */

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
  header {
    grid-template: "logo searchbar hamburgermenu" auto / 6.75% auto 25%;
  }
  .subheader {
    grid-template: ". telephone-content ." auto / 6.75% auto 25%;
  }
  #grid-wrapper {
    grid-template: "header header header" 66px "subheader subheader subheader" 55px "left main right" auto / 6.75% auto 25%;
  }
}


/* MOBILE VIEW */

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  header {
    grid-template: "logo searchbar hamburgermenu" auto / 66px auto 66px;
  }
  .subheader {
    grid-template: "telephone-content telephone-content telephone-content" auto / 66px auto 66px;
  }
  #grid-wrapper {
    grid-template: "header header header" 66px "subheader subheader subheader" 55px "left main right" auto / 6.75% auto 25%;
  }
  #left {
    /* grid-row: 1 / span 2; */
  }
  #right {
    /* grid-column: 2 / 3; */
  }
  main,
  #right {
    grid-column: 2 / span 2;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="grid-wrapper">
  <header>
    <div id="logo">
      <h1>Logo</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="searchbar">
      <p>Header stuff</p>
    </div>
    <div id="hamburgermenu">
      <h1>...</h1>
    </div>
  </header>
  <div class="subheader">
    <p class="telephone-content">Dit is telefoon informatie</p>
  </div>
  <aside id="left">
    <h1>Left</h1>
  </aside>
  <main>
    <h1>Content</h1>
    <p>Saaie boel</p>
  </main>
  <aside id="right">
    <h1>Right</h1>
  </aside>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you have in your mobile view:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    #grid-wrapper {
        grid-template: "header header header" 66px 
                       "subheader subheader subheader" 55px
                       "left main right" auto / 6.75% auto 25%;
  }
```

This layout produces three rows and three columns.

- row heights: 66px 55px auto
- column widths: 6.75% auto 25%

But you want `right` to appear underneath `main` (or vice versa?). So try this instead:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    #grid-wrapper {
        grid-template: "header header header" 66px
                       "subheader subheader subheader" 55px
                       "left main main" auto    /* adjustment */
                       "left right right" auto  /* new row */
                       / 6.75% auto 25%;
    }
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/X3nlF5Jx3vSdUm52DoyZ?p=preview

Comment: Cheers. Looks good. I did have something like that. But it seems that `grid-template` doesn't work if you don't put the column width definition at the bottom row.

Comment: It doesn't need to come at the bottom row ([revised demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/5Z29RlS87Q7y5dVo2kTJ?p=preview)). It just needs to come *after* the other rules, per the [definition syntax requirements](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#explicit-grid-shorthand).

Comment: Yea that's what I meant :). My mistake was thinking I could define column width anywhere. Lesson learned!